# How to "clean" PDF to remove non-text and non-images in Product User Manual?

Tags: malware, pdf

I need guidance on, with the least security risk, how to edit Product User Manuals and Engineering Drawings PDFs from the internet.

Antivirus is insufficient, according to advice from a [website](https://blog.fileformat.com/2021/10/16/malicious-pdf-files-and-how-to-protect-from-these/#:%7E:text=Stop%20PDF%20readers%20to%20execute%20non-PDF%20files%20Ensure,opening%20PDF%20attachments%20sent%20by%20unknown%20email%20sender%22https://blog.fileformat.com/2021/10/16/malicious-pdf-files-and-how-to-protect-from-these/#:%7E:text=Stop%20PDF%20readers%20to%20execute%20non-PDF%20files%20Ensure,opening%20PDF%20attachments%20sent%20by%20unknown%20email%20sender%22) which advises:

1. avoid unknown sender
2. ensure PDF is not executable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Effectiveness of flattening a PDF to remove malware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103323/effectiveness-of-flattening-a-pdf-to-remove-malware), [What is the safest way to deal with loads of incoming PDF files, some of which could potentially be malicious?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/151300/what-is-the-safest-way-to-deal-with-loads-of-incoming-pdf-files-some-of-which-c)

Comment: Sandboxing it would've been fine. Windows has Windows Sandbox. If it is a large operation, get a new laptop, clone the drive, and go wild. Afterwards, replace the HDD.

Comment: There is a range of tools called Content Disarm & Reconstruction for this very problem. It copies text and images into new files, leaving anything else behind.

Comment: Questions about where to find products or which products integrate with other products are off-topic here.

Comment: I need Enterprise solution for an average end-user. At home, Hyper-V would work.